# What is the time complexity of popping an element from a dict in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

This is kind of a combinatorics problem. I have a very large list, `all_possible`—which stores all of the possible values—and a very large `dict`, `present`, which stores all of the actually present values, e.g.:

```
all_possible = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
present = {1: 'some_value', 3: 'some_other_value'}
```

Currently, my search looks a bit like:

```
for key in all_possible:
    value = present.get(key, None)
    if value is None:
        do_something_if_key_not_present()
    else:
        do_something_if_key_is_present()
```

This works nicely, since for each iteration there is only one lookup in the dictionary, and the average lookup time for a Python dictionary [is O(1)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

However, amortized worst case lookup time is O(N), and since the dictionary can be so huge (millions of elements), one of the optimizations I've considered involves popping the elements from the dict as I traverse (so subsequent lookups have a smaller search space):

```
for key in all_possible:
    value = present.pop(key, None)  # this line changes, dict shrinks
    if value is None:
        do_something_if_key_not_present()
    else:
        do_something_if_key_is_present()
```

My question is **what is the time complexity of the dictionary `pop`?** I know that average case `pop` operations in structures like `list` are O(N), but I cannot find any reliable documentation that denotes the complexity of popping from a `dict`. If it ends up being O(1), this may speed up my search, but if it's any higher, I might be hurting myself.

Comment: Why not try some tests to time the two implementations?  I would suspect it would be `O(1)` though.  The only reason I can think that it would be `O(N)` in a list would be due to any element-shifting you'd have to do after removing the element of interest.

Comment: This code is running on Spark executors right now, so it's been very difficult to regard any time differences on (smaller) sample data as a result of the "optimization." I suppose I could test this on something locally, though

Comment: Create ```all_possible``` as a set instead of a list and use set methods to to determine what is or isn't *present* - then perform the processes as appropriate.

Comment: If you make `all_possible` a set  instead of a list, then `present = all_possible & set(present)` and `not_present = all_possible - set(present)` -- should be much faster than a for loop..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The time complexity of `dict.pop` is exactly the same as that of `dict.get`. `list.pop` is O(N) because it needs to shift elements, but `dict.pop` doesn't do that.

That said, `dict.pop` probably won't improve your lookup time. Deleting a key from a dict needs to leave a `DKIX_DUMMY` marker in its place, and the lookup routine needs to treat any `DKIX_DUMMY` it finds as if it were a hash collision, and keep going. At best, you'll save some `==` comparisons on deleted keys.

Even if `dict.pop` were an improvement, it wouldn't save you from O(N) worst-case lookup time. If you need to deal with adversarial key choices, dicts may not be a good fit for your use case.

Comment: Ahh this is great info. I had no idea it was replacing the missing key with a dummy marker, and I'm too C-illiterate to have discerned that from its source. Thank you very much for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: to be clear, list.pop(n)  when n points to the last element in an array is O(1) because there is no need to shift the elements, whereas any other index will cause a shift and is O(n).